# How do I link to a 3rd party Swift framework

Tags: swift

In the last 24 hours I've tried to consume two different 3rd party Swift libraries: [Swiftz](https://github.com/typelift/swiftz) and [Sleipnir](https://github.com/railsware/Sleipnir). I assume it should be fairly easy as both projects simply provide a sketch of how to consume them. However, neither provide enough detail for me to follow. I've tried all of the following: add the projects to my workspace, drag/drop the compiled frameworks into my project navigator, add the frameworks to the "Link Binary with Libraries" phase. In all cases, I get a linker error informing me that the framework can't be found.

I just need a link to the actual documentation that explains how to do this. I haven't been able to find it.

Edit: Forget about 3rd party libraries even. How do you consume your own libraries? I have a Cocoa Framework library I've written. Now I've added a command line project to the same workspace. Sure would be nice if I could access my new framework from my command line app. I clicked on my command line project. Clicked on Build Phases and dragged my custom framework to the Link Binary with Libraries section. Everything compiles fine. When running my app I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAppKit.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mgwelch/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftParsing-
  btkaoklayoffujgrkklfyffpipih/Build/Products/Debug/Parsing.framework/Versions/A/
  Parsing
  Reason: image not foundI
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/swift/ <-- this swift?

Comment: Yes, that's the one I mean.

Comment: You should be able to just drag and drop the framework's project file from Finder into the project you want to use it in (the framework project must *not* be opened in Xcode at that time). I do that all the time ;) those are so called subprojects and they automatically build with your project. You just need to add the framework's target in the project you want to add the framework to (link with binary or something like that, when you click on your project file it's in the first tab at the very bottom).

Comment: Thanks @HAS. I appreciate knowing this SHOULD work. It's proven to be more difficult than it sounds.If you look at my answer below, you'll see I'm still encountering two issues: initially a linker error and now an error in copy files phase (not sure if the copy file phase is really necessary. I'd think XCode would be smart enough to know it needs the files I've told it to link to.)

Comment: I looked a little more closely at the dyld error. I thought it was saying it couldn't find my Parsing.framework library. Rather, it's saying it can't find a swift library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, not many users are familiar with Swift frameworks yet, I guess.

Well, I'm getting some assistance from a framework developer over on an issue I raised on how to consumer their framework. I still have issues, but others may be interested in following the conversation to see some of the steps involved

https://github.com/typelift/swiftz/issues/114

Detailed instructions are provided at this issue. Feel free to try them. I'll mark this as closed.

UPDATE
I stated this in a comment but it might not be seen. I was trying to write a command line tool. At this time with XCode 6.1 it does not appear possible to use a third party framework in a command line tool. As a matter of fact I've written up an issue against another project stating that their command line targets no longer run: https://github.com/railsware/Sleipnir/issues/17

Perhaps this worked in a previous beta version, but it no longer seems possible.

Comment: I continue to get a runtime error: `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAppKit.dylib`

Comment: I was attempting to write a command-line app and according to one of the contributors of the swiftz projects, you can't use dylibs with command-line projects, something that I think would be nice if XCode informed you of when you attempted to do just that.

Comment: I also wanted to write a command line tool. Is this still not possible in XCode 6.4?

Comment: Xcode 7.1.1, trying to create an example CLI app for a framework I created explicitly for CLI apps, and… getting this stupid error. So this appears to still be a problem. Holy crap, this is beyond stupid, Apple. Guess I'll rewrite this thing as just flat Swift code, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking `Runpath Search Paths` in Build Settings. Check if the relative path to Frameworks directory is correct.

```
LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) @executable_path/../Frameworks @loader_path/Frameworks
```

Comment: Thanks. See my updated comment. According to my findings, what I was attempting to do just isn't possible in XCode 6.1. But I ask everyone I encounter if they can do it. Can you write a command line tool and link it to a third party framework? If so, you'd have some data to contradict my findings.

Comment: To answer your question: My "Runpath Search Paths" entry was blank. I copy/pasted your suggestion for a value. Now I get an error `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib`. So it seems like we've changed the symptoms of the problem a bit. Before it was looking for libswiftAppKit, but I don't know that for sure. This was all a few weeks ago and I was trying with a different project then. But what I'm trying to do now is the same (link to a framework), just a different project.

Comment: This is the first time I was told this just wasn't possible currently: https://github.com/typelift/swiftz/issues/114#issuecomment-62075011

Answer (score 2):

Check out the following document ([Embedded Swift frameworks in OS X command line tools](http://colemancda.github.io/programming/2015/02/12/embedded-swift-frameworks-osx-command-line-tools/)), it describes a process that works for embedding Swift frameworks in command line tools.

It's more of a work-around than a solution but it works. Ideally, the folks at Apple should put a friendly sign in large, bold, red letters when creating a command line app in Swift to avoid us wasting time with issues like this.

I've followed the process for Swift 1.1 and Swift 1.2 without any issues. The only tricky bit it to get argv to swift, but you can do this in objective-c in main.m with:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableArray *paramArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i=0; i<argc ;i++) {
            [paramArray addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:argv[i]]];
        }
        return (int) [[Whatever sharedInstance]manage:argc param:paramArray];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: @ColemanCDA this requires that the command line tool is written in Objective-C? Do you know if this is still the case for Swift2 / XCode 7?

Comment: Have you been able to install this as a command line app to be run from the real shell, and not just run it in XCode's pseudo terminal?

Comment: @Balthazar Yes, without any issues. I didn't create an installer for it but it executed fine from bash. Just needs to be added to the path and it will work just like any other command.

Comment: Too bad I gave it up then. I tried to replicate the exact steps at the page you referred to, and using the Objective-C code above. It compiled fine in XCode, also with "Release" configuration and after thorough cleaning. It could be run in the pseudo terminal without issues, but trying to build it with "xcodebuild install" didn't work. It would normally install the file to a path that's already in PATH. I have created many command line tools this way, so I know the steps, but couldn't make it work with the above description. I gave it up and made it a simple GUI application instead.

Comment: @AdaptiveCoder This process didn't work for me? Are you still doing this at all in any of your work and having success with it?