# Error Importing Swift Files Through CocoaPods

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

I am currently trying to integrate Swift and Objective-C files over to my Swift project through CocoaPods. PubNub (the Objective-C project) was imported fine through a bridging header. However, when I tried importing CryptoSwift (Swift project) with "import CrytoSwift", it gives me the following dyld error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAppKit.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/vincent.tseng/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/lib-gcqzleazyubhgqekdwrdragwauor/Build/Products/Debug/CryptoSwift.framework/Versions/A/CryptoSwift
  Reason: image not found
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a CLI application? It appears it's [not currently possible to use frameworks in a Swift CLI app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691653/how-do-i-link-to-a-3rd-party-swift-framework). Thanks, Apple.