# How to use carthage libraries when making a Swift Command line tool?

Tags: xcode, carthage

I'm getting the error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libclang.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/hakonbogen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftFormat-edvvyjtkenmgpacnoypycvtuxctn/Build/Products/Debug/SourceKittenFramework.framework/SourceKittenFramework
  Reason: image not found
```

When trying to build my command line tool in XCode. I've built carthage so the frameworks are in correct folder.
[image]

And done Link Binary With Libraries:
[image]

I also tried  adding Copy files
[image]

But nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This will explain your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630911/using-frameworks-in-a-command-line-tool (possible duplicate too)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I link to a 3rd party Swift framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691653/how-do-i-link-to-a-3rd-party-swift-framework)